# Method Not Calling When Button's Clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Am I missing something? Here I am using Rails 4.2.5 with Ruby 2.2.3.

```
...

#routes.rb

   get '/users/:user_id/account/:id' => 'foo#bar', as: 'foo_bar'

...
```

Controller:

```
...

#foo_controller.rb

def bar
  flash[:warning] = "You have found Bar!."
  #return redirect_to x <--- still nothing!
end

...
```

Using Zurb Foundation 6:

```
<%= link_to 'Get', foo_bar_path, class: "input-group-button button", method: :get %>
```

When button is pressed, I got back this in the console:

> Started GET "/users/1/account/2" for ::1 at 2016-02-11 17:11:04 +0000
>   Processing by FooController#show as HTML
>     Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"IT5zcHymgnHqiN1y7SMmMVkL+JlSisKels62qMXy3Y3cD+XXDlGsey/TistN3JaE2a8vZwx/xycUQrQId0Rpsw==", "user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}

How to properly call a method via link_to?

Edited:

Rendered html of button:

```
<a class="input-group-button button" data-method="get" href="/users/1/account/2">Submit</a>
```

Comment: What is the rendered out html (ie the `a` tag) created by the link_to?  Can you add that to your question please?

Comment: Routes will use the first route it finds, reading down from the top of the routes.rb file, which matches the url.  Perhaps you need to move the route you listed above another route in there which is being used?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes correct about the route order. Sorted. Now Im getting Missing Template. I only need to run the method and thats it.